# GNU Make error when compiling JDK8 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: makefile

```
/usr/bin/make -s VERBOSE="-s" LOG_LEVEL="warn" -R -I /work/jdk8/make/common -f adlc.make -r `/work/jdk8/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/hotspot/linux_amd64_compiler2/fastdebug/../generated/adjust-mflags "-nrRs -I/work/jdk8/make/common -I/work/jdk8/make/common -I/work/jdk8/make/common -I/work/jdk8/make/common -I/work/jdk8/make/common -j1" "16"`

/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '8'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '/'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 'a'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '/'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: make [options] [target]
```

...

make version: GNU Make 4.2.1

Anybody knows this? Thanks.

Comment: you use backquotes on your `-r` option, which means it's running some sort of shell script to generate those options.   Try running that manually and see what it outputs.